# Mongodb geospatial index vs GoogleMaps Directions Service

Tags: google-maps, mongodb, google-maps-api-3, geospatial

I recently worked on a small project on location-based services and my intention was to locate the nearest cab (GPS fitted) within a given radius of a requesting passenger (GPS enabled Android phone). I wanted to use MongoDB's geospatial indexes, but it turned out that geospatial indexes work on lat-longs and they calculate *displacement* between two points, not the *distance*. In my case, search was confined within a city, and I had to go for GoogleMaps Directions Service because it tells the distance as *on the road*, estimated time taken etc.

Does this mean that geospatial indexes make sense only when displacement is large enough, so that distance and displacement becomes essentially the same?

Answer (score 3):

Geospatial indexes have the goal of having fast data retrieval based on position on a multi-dimensional space. If you have the cab position data in a MongoDB database you could use a geospatial index to fastly select a reduced set of cabs which are more likely to be the closest one, but still you'd have to calculate the distance on the road (and eventually the drive time) using an algorythm on the road network.

For example you know that if the closest (in straight line) cab is at 20km from you (measured through the road), you know that any cab outside the 20km radius will surely be further away (on the road) than the first one you found, so you're not interested in them.
You can then use MongoDB spatial index to get all the cabs in 20km radius and then you can find among them which one has the minimum distance.

Comment: agreed and then use the Google Maps API Distance Matrix to find the distances between your subset of data.

Comment: @pqnet thanks for the reply, but the cab at 21km displacement could actually be nearer on road than the one at 20km displacement (imagine a straight road  for 21km and a curvy road for 20km)..and MongoDB wouldn't know this..that's exactly my problem :(

Comment: a curvy road can't be shorter than a straight road. That's a basic triangle property.

Comment: at least on euclidean spaces: since you're on a quasi-spherical surface you could need to calculate the geodetic (or at least a lower bound for it), but still you can be sure that going straight from A to B is shorter or equal to any path going from A to B.

Comment: A comparison of driving routes to find the "nearest car" is not strictly a geospatial query, it is an evaluation of several factors including: driving distance, travel time, and traffic flow restrictions.  Using a quick geo search to narrow down the candidates to provide to a [Distance Matrix](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distancematrix/) would be a good approach (nice API pointed out by @ManoMarks!).

Comment: @AafreenSheikh  reading in 2022 I realize the wording is confusing. What I meant to say is that you find your closest cab using spatial db (so the closest in a straight line) then you compute the distance on the road (using google maps api or similar) and find it is 20 km of road. You then know that any other cab which is outside the 20km radius circle is definitely further than the first cab and so you aren't interested in them.